# How to make the Camera rotate more than one time?

Tags: camera, edit-mode

How can I circle the camera around more than one time?

[image]

Hope you can help me.

Comment: Try to unparent the camera from the curve then add the camera a follow path constraint

Comment: @Joel, I edited your original post to include your video as animated GIF. In the future, please try to create and attach it yourself (https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963/what-is-the-process-for-creating-gifs-for-questions-and-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Double turn around a circular path -

[image]

Add a curve --> circle.  Set your total frames in the timeline to say 250.

In the path's geometry properties, set the "Frames" to 200.

At frame 1 keyframe the path's Evaluation time" which should be showing 0.000

Take the timeline cursor to (e,g,) frame 240.

In the Path's properties, set it's "Evaluation" time to twice that in the 'Frames' slot. (400) and  keyframe that.

[image]

Set an empty or other object to follow the path.